# Postgresql hash join performance

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it normal that left join of two tables:

```
table1 (ca. 100 000 000 rows)
table2 (20 rows)
```

takes more than 3 minutes? Is it ok time for tables of such sizes?

EDIT: EXPLAIN ANALZE

```
Hash Left Join  (cost=3.24..17417579.49 rows=96985400 width=70) (actual time=0.166..219005.717 rows=96985400 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (vosdn.rok = rai.rok_analizy)
  ->  Seq Scan on view_odcinki_scenariusze_10_do_nothing vosdn  (cost=0.00..13174465.00 rows=96985400 width=44) (actual time=0.024..63402.774 rows=96985400 loops=1)
  ->  Hash  (cost=2.99..2.99 rows=20 width=16) (actual time=0.078..0.081 rows=20 loops=1)
        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
        ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=1.45..2.99 rows=20 width=16) (actual time=0.058..0.073 rows=20 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (zpi.rok = rai.rok)
              ->  Seq Scan on "zmiana_PKB_id" zpi  (cost=0.00..1.25 rows=25 width=14) (actual time=0.014..0.016 rows=25 loops=1)
              ->  Hash  (cost=1.20..1.20 rows=20 width=4) (actual time=0.033..0.034 rows=20 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                    ->  Seq Scan on rok_analizy_id rai  (cost=0.00..1.20 rows=20 width=4) (actual time=0.021..0.024 rows=20 loops=1)
Planning Time: 42.591 ms
Execution Time: 221538.454 ms
```

QUERY:

```
SELECT vosdn.id_odcinka_obl,
    vosdn.id_scenariusz,
    vosdn.dlugosc,
    vosdn.klasa_drog_id,
    vosdn.przekroj_id,
    vosdn.nmt_rodzaj_terenu_id,
    vosdn.obszar_id,
    vosdn.rok AS rok_analizy,
    rai.rok,
    zpi."zmiana_PKB",
    zpi.zmiana_pkb_skumul_2020 AS "zmiana_PKB_skumul",
    vosdn.inmop_2015_vcur_so * "_modul_kosztowy_dr".const_we_so() * (zpi.zmiana_pkb_skumul - 1) so,
    vosdn.inmop_2015_vcur_sd * "_modul_kosztowy_dr".const_we_sd() * (zpi.zmiana_pkb_skumul - 1) sd,
    vosdn.inmop_2015_vcur_sc * "_modul_kosztowy_dr".const_we_sc() * (zpi.zmiana_pkb_skumul - 1) sc,
    vosdn.inmop_2015_vcur_scp * "_modul_kosztowy_dr".const_we_scp() * (zpi.zmiana_pkb_skumul - 1) scp
   FROM _odcinki_scenariusze_dr.view_odcinki_scenariusze_10_do_nothing vosdn
     LEFT JOIN _modul_kosztowy_dr.rok_analizy_id rai ON rai.rok_analizy = vosdn.rok
     LEFT JOIN _modul_kosztowy_dr."zmiana_PKB_id" zpi ON zpi.rok = rai.rok
```

First table

```
table _odcinki_scenariusze_dr.view_odcinki_scenariusze_10_do_nothing is        Materialized view "_odcinki_scenariusze_dr.view_odcinki_scenariusze_10_do_nothing"
               Column               |           Type            | Collation | Nullable | Default
------------------------------------+---------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id_odcinka_obl                     | integer                   |           |          |
 nr_drogi_j                         | character varying(10)     |           |          |
 numer_porzadkowy                   | smallint                  |           |          |
 kierunek_ruchu_id                  | smallint                  |           |          |
 id_pasa_ruchu                      | smallint                  |           |          |
 geom                               | geometry(LineString,2180) |           |          |
 liczba_jezdni                      | smallint                  |           |          |
 liczba_pasow                       | smallint                  |           |          |
 klasa_drog_id                      | smallint                  |           |          |
 przebieg_miasto_na_prawach_powiatu | boolean                   |           |          |
 wojewodztwo_id                     | smallint                  |           |          |
 zrodlo_danych_o_pasach_id          | smallint                  |           |          |
 przekroj_id                        | smallint                  |           |          |
 nawierzchnia_id                    | smallint                  |           |          |
 nawierzchnia_jezdnia_id            | smallint                  |           |          |
 szerokosc                          | real                      |           |          |
 dlugosc                            | real                      |           |          |
 szerokosc_jezdnia                  | real                      |           |          |
 e_pow_jezdnia                      | real                      |           |          |
 rok_budowy_jezdnia                 | smallint                  |           |          |
 obszar_id                          | smallint                  |           |          |
 dsn_aona_sp_avg                    | real                      |           |          |
 dsn_aona_ss_avg                    | real                      |           |          |
 dsn_aona_data_min                  | text                      |           |          |
 dsn_mpdc_mpd_1_avg                 | real                      |           |          |
 dsn_mpdc_data_min                  | real                      |           |          |
 dsn_iric_slad_l_avg                | real                      |           |          |
 dsn_iric_slad_p_avg                | real                      |           |          |
 dsn_iric_data_min                  | real                      |           |          |
 dsn_kolc_l_kol_avg                 | real                      |           |          |
 dsn_kolc_p_kol_avg                 | real                      |           |          |
 dsn_kolc_data_min                  | real                      |           |          |
 dsn_up_sci300_avg                  | real                      |           |          |
 dsn_up_dst0_avg                    | real                      |           |          |
 dsn_up_data_min                    | real                      |           |          |
 dsn_wtp_mim_avg                    | real                      |           |          |
 dsn_wtp_data_min                   | real                      |           |          |
 zrodlo_dsn_id                      | smallint                  |           |          |
 brd_kwzo                           | real                      |           |          |
 brd_kwzo_ak_id                     | smallint                  |           |          |
 brd_kwzpr                          | real                      |           |          |
 brd_kwzpr_kl_id                    | smallint                  |           |          |
 brd_kwzpr_ak_id                    | smallint                  |           |          |
 brd_kwzm                           | real                      |           |          |
 brd_kwzm_kl_id                     | smallint                  |           |          |
 brd_kwzm_ak_id                     | smallint                  |           |          |
 brd_gkwn                           | real                      |           |          |
 brd_gkw_ak_id                      | smallint                  |           |          |
 brd_prkwn                          | real                      |           |          |
 brd_prkw_kl_id                     | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2015_capacity                | real                      |           |          |
 inmop_2015_v0_so                   | real                      |           |          |
 inmop_2015_v0_sd                   | real                      |           |          |
 inmop_2015_v0_sc                   | real                      |           |          |
 inmop_2015_v0_scp                  | real                      |           |          |
 inmop_2015_v0_b                    | real                      |           |          |
 inmop_2015_vcur_so                 | real                      |           |          |
 inmop_2015_vcur_sd                 | real                      |           |          |
 inmop_2015_vcur_sc                 | real                      |           |          |
 inmop_2015_vcur_scp                | real                      |           |          |
 inmop_2015_vcur_b                  | real                      |           |          |
 inmop_2015_vol_so                  | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2015_vol_sd                  | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2015_vol_sc                  | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2015_vol_scp                 | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2015_vol_b                   | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2020_v0_so                   | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2025_v0_so                   | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2030_v0_so                   | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2035_v0_so                   | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2040_v0_so                   | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2045_v0_so                   | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2020_v0_sd                   | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2025_v0_sd                   | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2030_v0_sd                   | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2035_v0_sd                   | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2040_v0_sd                   | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2045_v0_sd                   | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2020_v0_sc                   | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2025_v0_sc                   | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2030_v0_sc                   | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2035_v0_sc                   | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2040_v0_sc                   | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2045_v0_sc                   | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2020_v0_scp                  | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2025_v0_scp                  | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2030_v0_scp                  | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2035_v0_scp                  | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2040_v0_scp                  | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2045_v0_scp                  | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2020_v0_b                    | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2025_v0_b                    | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2030_v0_b                    | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2035_v0_b                    | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2040_v0_b                    | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2045_v0_b                    | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2020_vcur_so                 | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2025_vcur_so                 | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2030_vcur_so                 | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2035_vcur_so                 | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2040_vcur_so                 | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2045_vcur_so                 | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2020_vcur_sd                 | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2025_vcur_sd                 | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2030_vcur_sd                 | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2035_vcur_sd                 | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2040_vcur_sd                 | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2045_vcur_sd                 | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2020_vcur_sc                 | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2025_vcur_sc                 | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2030_vcur_sc                 | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2035_vcur_sc                 | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2040_vcur_sc                 | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2045_vcur_sc                 | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2020_vcur_scp                | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2025_vcur_scp                | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2030_vcur_scp                | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2035_vcur_scp                | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2040_vcur_scp                | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2045_vcur_scp                | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2020_vcur_b                  | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2025_vcur_b                  | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2030_vcur_b                  | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2035_vcur_b                  | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2040_vcur_b                  | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2045_vcur_b                  | smallint                  |           |          |
 inmop_2020_vol_so                  | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2025_vol_so                  | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2030_vol_so                  | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2035_vol_so                  | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2040_vol_so                  | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2045_vol_so                  | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2020_vol_sd                  | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2025_vol_sd                  | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2030_vol_sd                  | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2035_vol_sd                  | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2040_vol_sd                  | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2045_vol_sd                  | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2020_vol_sc                  | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2025_vol_sc                  | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2030_vol_sc                  | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2035_vol_sc                  | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2040_vol_sc                  | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2045_vol_sc                  | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2020_vol_scp                 | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2025_vol_scp                 | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2030_vol_scp                 | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2035_vol_scp                 | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2040_vol_scp                 | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2045_vol_scp                 | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2020_vol_b                   | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2025_vol_b                   | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2030_vol_b                   | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2035_vol_b                   | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2040_vol_b                   | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2045_vol_b                   | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2050_capacity                | real                      |           |          |
 inmop_2050_v0_so                   | real                      |           |          |
 inmop_2050_v0_sd                   | real                      |           |          |
 inmop_2050_v0_sc                   | real                      |           |          |
 inmop_2050_v0_scp                  | real                      |           |          |
 inmop_2050_v0_b                    | real                      |           |          |
 inmop_2050_vcur_so                 | real                      |           |          |
 inmop_2050_vcur_sd                 | real                      |           |          |
 inmop_2050_vcur_sc                 | real                      |           |          |
 inmop_2050_vcur_scp                | real                      |           |          |
 inmop_2050_vcur_b                  | real                      |           |          |
 inmop_2050_vol_so                  | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2050_vol_sd                  | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2050_vol_sc                  | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2050_vol_scp                 | integer                   |           |          |
 inmop_2050_vol_b                   | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr05_geometria_id                 | smallint                  |           |          |
 gpr05_sdr                          | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr05_sdrm                         | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr05_sdrd                         | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr05_sdro                         | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr05_sdrc                         | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr05_sdra                         | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr05_sdrcp                        | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr05_sdrr                         | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr05_sdrt                         | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr10_geometria_id                 | smallint                  |           |          |
 gpr10_sdr                          | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr10_sdrm                         | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr10_sdrd                         | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr10_sdro                         | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr10_sdrc                         | real                      |           |          |
 gpr10_sdra                         | real                      |           |          |
 gpr10_sdrcp                        | real                      |           |          |
 gpr10_sdrr                         | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr10_sdrt                         | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr10_sdrccp                       | real                      |           |          |
 gpr10_sdrccpa                      | real                      |           |          |
 gpr15_geometria_id                 | smallint                  |           |          |
 gpr15_nr2010                       | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_nr2015                       | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_nazwa_odc_id                 | smallint                  |           |          |
 gpr15_rok_pom                      | character varying(4)      |           |          |
 gpr15_nr_dro_gpr                   | character varying(6)      |           |          |
 gpr15_nr_dro_sr                    | text                      |           |          |
 gpr15_nr_jez_sr                    | character varying         |           |          |
 gpr15_nr_jez_gpr                   | character varying(1)      |           |          |
 gpr15_nr_odcinka_sr                | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_sdrr2015                     | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_sdrl2015                     | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_sdrz2015                     | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_sdrc2015                     | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_sdrrp1                       | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_sdrrp2                       | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_sdrrp3                       | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_sdrrp4                       | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_sdrrp5                       | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_sdrrp6                       | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_sdrrp7                       | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_sdrrp8                       | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_sdrlp1                       | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_sdrlp2                       | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_sdrlp3                       | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_sdrlp4                       | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_sdrlp5                       | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_sdrlp6                       | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_sdrlp7                       | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_sdrzp1                       | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_sdrzp2                       | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_sdrzp3                       | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_sdrzp4                       | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_sdrzp5                       | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_sdrzp6                       | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_sdrzp7                       | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_sdr2010                      | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_sdr2010p1                    | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_sdr2010p2                    | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_sdr2010p3                    | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_sdr2010p4                    | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_sdr2010p5                    | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_sdr2010p6                    | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_sdr2010p7                    | integer                   |           |          |
 gpr15_ile_jezdni                   | smallint                  |           |          |
 gpr15_szer                         | real                      |           |          |
 gpr15_char_id                      | smallint                  |           |          |
 gpr15_losi                         | smallint                  |           |          |
 gpr15_kr_id                        | smallint                  |           |          |
 gpr15_klasa_id                     | smallint                  |           |          |
 gpr15_klasa30                      | smallint                  |           |          |
 gpr15_losi_s                       | real                      |           |          |
 gpr15_kr_s_id                      | smallint                  |           |          |
 gpr15_losi_p                       | real                      |           |          |
 gpr15_kr_p_id                      | smallint                  |           |          |
 mof_id                             | smallint                  |           |          |
 mof_typ_id                         | smallint                  |           |          |
 mof_rodzaj                         | smallint                  |           |          |
 mof_miejscowosc                    | text                      |           |          |
 nmt_rodzaj_terenu_id               | smallint                  |           |          |
 id_scenariusz                      | integer                   |           |          |
 scenariusz                         | bigint                    |           |          |
 rok                                | bigint                    |           |          |
 wsk_ini                            | bigint                    |           |          |
 alpha                              | double precision          |           |          |
 zabieg                             | bigint                    |           |          |
 przed_zabiegiem                    | double precision          |           |          |
 po_zabiegu                         | double precision          |           |          |
 przed_zabiegiem_dn                 | double precision          |           |          |
 po_zabiegu_dn                      | double precision          |           |          |
Indexes:
    "view_odcinki_scenariusze_10_do_nothing_id_odcinka_obl_idx" btree (id_odcinka_obl, id_pasa_ruchu, klasa_drog_id, wojewodztwo_id, przekroj_id, zrodlo_danych_o_pasach_id, kierunek_ruchu_id, nr_drogi_j, numer_porzadkowy, nawierzchnia_jezdnia_id, nawierzchnia_id, szerokosc, dlugosc, szerokosc_jezdnia, rok, scenariusz, id_scenariusz, wsk_ini, alpha, zabieg)
```

Second table

```
       Table "_modul_kosztowy_dr.rok_analizy_id"
   Column    |   Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default
-------------+----------+-----------+----------+---------
 id_rekordu  | smallint |           |          |
 rok_analizy | smallint |           |          |
 rok         | smallint |           |          |
Indexes:
    "rok_analizy_id_rok_analizy_idx" btree (rok_analizy, rok)
```

Third table

```
              Table "_modul_kosztowy_dr.zmiana_PKB_id"
         Column         |   Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default
------------------------+----------+-----------+----------+---------
 id_rekordu             | integer  |           |          |
 rok                    | smallint |           |          |
 zmiana_PKB             | real     |           |          |
 zmiana_pkb_skumul      | real     |           |          |
 zmiana_pkb_skumul_2020 | real     |           |          |
Indexes:
    "zmiana_pkb_id_rok_idx" btree (rok)
```

Comment: This is unanswerable with the information available. To get an answer you will need to provide the text of the query and the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` (see here [EXPLAIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html) for more info) output of the query.

Comment: show us execution plan by running `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, COSTS, VERBOSE, BUFFERS)`. also provide tables information including existing indices plus your query

Comment: added results of EXPLAIN ANALYZE

Comment: You still have not shown the query itself.

Comment: I'm not sure the kitchen sink index you have on `view_odcinki_scenariusze_10_do_nothing` is doing you any good. Would it not be better on just `rok`. Also not sure what `vosdn.rok AS rok_analizy` is doing when you could have `rai.rok_analizy`?

Comment: What is this `"_modul_kosztowy_dr".const_we_so()` ? A scalar function?